# Remove duplicates (1 to many) or write a subquery that solves my problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery, duplicates

Referring to the diagram below the records table has unique Records. Each record is updated, via comments through an Update Table. When I join the two I get lots of duplicates.

1. How to remove duplicates? Group By does not work for me as I have more than 10 fields in select query and some of them are functions.
2. Write a sub query which pulls the last updates in the Update table for each record that is updated *in a particular month*. Joining with this sub query will solve my problem.

Thanks!

**Edit**
Table structure that is of interest is

```
create table Records(
recordID int,
90more_fields various
)

create table Updates(
update_id int,
record_id int,
comment text,
byUser varchar(25),
datecreate datetime
)
```

[image]

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Can you give us more details on the table schemas involved?

Comment: We need to know silly stuff like table structure and relationships to write a query...

Comment: MS-SQL 2005, WinXP. Orange = RecordID (primary key), Blue=Record_ID2 (this is the same as RecordID of Orange), this is the JOIN on variables. No relationship, assume they are independent otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
SELECT * /*But list columns explicitly*/
FROM   Orange o
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   Blue b
                    WHERE  b.datecreate >= '20110901'
                           AND b.datecreate < '20111001'
                           AND o.RecordID = b.Record_ID2
                    ORDER  BY b.datecreate  DESC) b
```

Comment: @SavageGarden - Try Joe's also. [It varies which one works out best](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/departments/optimizing-top-n-per-group-queries)

Comment: Everything looks fine. I need to put WHERE clause on orange table where do I put it in this query? If I do in the end `WHERE o.customerName = 'test'`, I get error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information available...

```
WITH cteLastUpdate AS (
    SELECT Record_ID2, UpdateDateTime, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Record_ID2 ORDER BY UpdateDateTime DESC) AS RowNUM
        FROM BlueTable
        /* Add WHERE clause if needed to restrict date range */
)
SELECT *
    FROM cteLastUpdate lu
        INNER JOIN OrangeTable o
            ON lu.Record_ID2 = o.RecordID
    WHERE lu.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Last updates per record and month:

```
SELECT *
  FROM UPDATES outerUpd
 WHERE exists
 (
      -- Magic part
      SELECT 1
        FROM UPDATES innerUpd
       WHERE innerUpd.RecordId = outerUpd.RecordId
    GROUP BY RecordId
           , date_part('year', innerUpd.datecolumn)
           , date_part('month', innerUpd.datecolumn)
      HAVING max(innerUpd.datecolumn) = outerUpd.datecolumn
 )
```

(Works on PostgreSQL, date_part is different in other RDBMS)